# Regex - get value after particular string

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to parse the following file:

```
Bond1G: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.117.60.138  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.117.61.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9e:30c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:9e:30:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1571806  bytes 172471361 (164.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10949  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 188023  bytes 51771764 (49.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I got some help for extracting the IP addresses for 'inet', 'netmask', and 'broadcast' however my troubles come with the Mac address style formatting as well as gathering values who's key also has a space in it.

My end goal is to grab the following:

1. search for 'inet6' and grab value up until a space
2. search for 'ether' and grab value up until a space
3. What about grabbing 'RX packets'? Can I just include that string in the search and take all until reaching a space?

interface being referenced:

> refer to the file snippet above which is an interface instance

code so far to fetch IP addresses:

```
info = {}

inetMatches = re.findall("inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s", interface) 
if (len(inetMatches) > 0):
    info['inet'] = inetMatches[0].replace('inet', '').strip()

netmaskMatches = re.findall("netmask [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s", interface)
if (len(netmaskMatches) > 0):
    info['netmask'] = netmaskMatches[0].replace('netmask', '').strip()

broadcastMatches = re.findall("broadcast [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s", interface)
if (len(broadcastMatches) > 0):
    info['broadcast'] = broadcastMatches[0].replace('broadcast', '').strip()

# tried to continue here but not working for me:
inet6Matches = re.findall("inet6 [^ ]* (.*)", interface)
if (len(inet6Matches) > 0):
    info['inet6'] = inet6Matches[0].replace('inet6', '').strip()  # this doesn't work for me

# TODO: grab 'ether'    
# TODO: grab 'RX packets'
# TODO: grab 'dropped'
# TODO: grab 'TX errors'
```

Any help with this regex would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there are capturing (normal) parentheses in a regex, "findall" will return only what matches in them. Use non-capturing `(?:`...`)` instead.

Comment: If this is the output of `ifconfig` I would recommend you use `/proc/net` and `/sys/class/net/` if possible to extract those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest regex for what you are looking for is this: `inet6 ([^ ]+)`.
It captures every character up until it finds a space.

You should probably use capturing parenthesis to get exactly what you need with the regex instead of replacing what doesn't match afterwards, it's cleaner and more readable in my opinion.

```
inetMatches = re.findall("inet ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})", interface) 
if (len(inetMatches) > 0):
    info['inet'] = inetMatches[0]

netmaskMatches = re.findall("netmask ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})", interface)
if (len(netmaskMatches) > 0):
    info['netmask'] = netmaskMatches[0]

broadcastMatches = re.findall("broadcast ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})", interface)
if (len(broadcastMatches) > 0):
    info['broadcast'] = broadcastMatches[0]

inet6Matches = re.findall("inet6 ([^ ]+)", interface)
if (len(inet6Matches) > 0):
    info['inet6'] = inet6Matches[0]
```

You can follow the same idea to match ether and RX packets.

For getting the dropped value from RX errors you could do something like this:

```
rxErrorsMatches = re.findall("RX errors.+dropped ([^ ]+)", interface)
if (len(rxErrorsMatches) > 0):
    info["rxErrors"] = rxErrorsMatches[0]
```

If you wanted to match several values at once, you could use `search` instead of `findall`:

```
rxErrorsMatches = re.search("RX errors ([^ ]+)\s+dropped ([^ ]+)", interface)
print(rxErrorsMatches.group(0)) #RX errors 0  dropped 10949
print(rxErrorsMatches.group(1)) #0
print(rxErrorsMatches.group(2)) #10949
```

Comment: So this seems helpful really. Here's a question for you, what about grabbing the 'dropped' value from 'RX' and 'TX' respectively? I can't do a 'findall' because it won't grab the appropriate value for key.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend using other sources to get this data if possible, if not I would attempt to use a single regex to extract all the info as key/value pairs. The following seems close enough:

```
(?P<key>(?:[RT]X [a-z]+)|[\w\d]+)[= ]+(?P<value>[^ ]+)(?: +(?P<opts>\(.+\)))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/yADPxs/1

Explanation:

- `(?P<key>`: start a capturing group with name "key"
- `(?:` start a non-capturing group (only used for "or")
- key can be either:

  - `[RT]X [a-z]+`: which handles 2-letter ones like "RX packets", or
  - `[\w\d]+`: letters and digits (we need digits here for "inet6")
- `[= ]+`: separator equals or space one or more times
- `(?P<value>[^ ]+)`: capture value as anything but space
- `(?: +(?P<opts>\(.+\)))?`:

  - A non capturing group which might or might not be there (`?` at the end)
  - With a capturing group inside that contains anything in parenthesis. handles "(124.2 MiB)"

You then need to loop the groups to find the key you are interested in and extract its value. Note that:

- RX/TX appears only in packets and while you are looping you might have to "remember" if you are on RX line or on TX one
- human-readable values in `<>` are parsed as part of the `value` (for example "0x20<link>")